# How to customize labels of a heatmap created using pyqtgraph?

Tags: pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm transitioning from tkinter with matplotlib to PyQt with pyqtgraph and wish to create a simple heatmap, with labels coming from a list of strings. I have no experience with PyQt nor pyqtgraph, and I'm having a hard time tracking down the means by which I can add the labels and adjust the fontsize. Here's what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout

import pyqtgraph as pg
pg.setConfigOption('background', 'lightgray')
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Heatmap")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightgray;")         
        self.resize(500,500)

        layout = QHBoxLayout() # using since I will later add widgets to this row

        graphWidget = pg.ImageView()
    
        graphWidget.setImage(np.random.rand(5,5))
        colors = [(0, 0, 0),(4, 5, 61),(84, 42, 55),(15, 87, 60),(208, 17, 141),(255, 
        255, 255)]
        cmap = pg.ColorMap(pos=np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 6), color=colors)
        graphWidget.setColorMap(cmap)
    
        layout.addWidget(graphWidget)
  
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

The output image looks like this:

[image]

What I'd like to do is the following:

1. Starting with a list of strings, `Labels=['a','b','c','d','e']`, place the
   labels along the horizontal and vertical axes, starting with 'a','a' in the lower
   left and ending with 'e','e' in the top right. The labels should be centered with
   respect to their corresponding squares.
2. Be able to adjust the font family and size of my labels.
3. Completely remove everything to the right of the heatmap itself and use a simple
   static colorbar as I did using matplotlib.

I will later be adding a slider for animation, along with other features, later.